# Decoding a json array with certain objects in Android

Tags: php, android, json

So, I am sending the below data as a json response to "client.execute()" method in Android code.

```
[{"groupId":"26","adminId":"33177","userId":"65515"},{"groupId":"26","adminId":"33177","userId":"95272"},{"groupId":"26","adminId":"33177","userId":"33177"},{"groupId":"1","adminId":"33177","userId":"95272"},{"groupId":"1","adminId":"33177","userId":"47020"}]
```

The code that was used to create this json data to be sent back to the Android app is as follows:

```
while($k<$i)
{       
    $qr = "SELECT groupId,adminId,userId FROM groupparticipants WHERE groupId='" . $groupId[$k] ."' AND adminId='" . $adminId[$k] . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$qr);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $finalres[$j]["groupId"]=$row['groupId'];
        $finalres[$j]["adminId"]=$row['adminId'];
        $finalres[$j]["userId"]=$row['userId'];
        $j++;
    }
    $k++;
}

    $finaljson = json_encode($finalres);
    echo $finaljson;
```

I was wondering how would I be decoding it in Android. Or is there any better reprsentation format that could have been sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would save the JSON response as a `String`, then just initialize a `JSONArray` like such:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
```

Assuming the value of `json` is the JSON resposne.

You can then get each `JSONObject` from the `JSONArray`.

Comment: And how to fetch individual values then ? So that I can display them in a listview or any other view in Android app.

Comment: You can create an `ArrayList` of whatever object you're sending (it looks like a type of user, so just create a POJO to hold the info), then catch each individual `JSONObject` with `jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)`. After you catch each `JSONObject`, you can get the actual data using `JSONObject.get("groupId")`, etc.

Comment: Okay! It's done. Can read values successfully. I'd suggest the readers of this questions to also go through the Gson wiki page[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson] and also the gson google page[http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/] and use gson for working with json stuff. It's good.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response looks very simple to parse.  I'd use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and create an object with the three fields you have in your response.  Refer to the accepted answer here for the parsing of the list of objects:

[How do I decode a list of string pairs with GSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824689/how-do-i-decode-a-list-of-string-pairs-with-gson)